# how to add website links in listView to use adapter

Tags: android, listview, hyperlink, clickable

It's my main activity...

public class InternationalActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_international);
    listView =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstInternational);


    String[] varsityName={"Alliance University","Anna University","Berkeley University","Caltech University","Columbia University","Cornell University","ETH switzerland University","Harvard University",
    "Imperial London University","Johns Hopkins University","Kyoto University","Mlchigan University","Manchester University","Massacusetts University","NewYork University","NorthWestern University ",
    "Oxford University","Princeton University","Stanford University","British Coulmbia University","Cambridge University","Chicago University","Copenhegen University","Kolkata University","University ofLondon",
    "Texas University","Tokio University","Toronto University","Pennsylvnia University","Washington University","Yale University"};

    int[] images = {alliance,R.drawable.anna,R.drawable.berkeley,R.drawable.caltech,R.drawable.columbia,
    R.drawable.cornell,R.drawable.eth,R.drawable.harvard,R.drawable.imperialcollegelondon,R.drawable.johnshopkins,
    R.drawable.kyotouniversity,R.drawable.mlchiganuniversity,R.drawable.manchesteruniversity,R.drawable.massacusettsinstitute,
    R.drawable.newyorkuniversity,R.drawable.northwesternuniversity,R.drawable.oxforduniversity,R.drawable.princetonuniversity,
    R.drawable.stanforduniversity,R.drawable.universitybritiscoulmbia,R.drawable.cambridge,R.drawable.universitychicago,
    R.drawable.universitycopenhegen,R.drawable.kolkata,R.drawable.london,R.drawable.universitytexas,R.drawable.universitytokio,
    R.drawable.universitytoronto,R.drawable.universitypennsylvania,R.drawable.washingtonuniversity,R.drawable.yaleuniversity};


    final InternationalAdapter internationalAdapter = new InternationalAdapter(this,varsityName,images);



    listView.setAdapter(internationalAdapter);

   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


       }
   });





}
```

}

and It's My adapter class...

public class InternationalAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
String[] names;
int[] varsityimg;
 Context context;


public static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public InternationalAdapter(InternationalActivity mainActivity, String[]namez, int[]imagess){
    names = namez;
    varsityimg = imagess;
    context = mainActivity;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return names.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}




public class MyHolder{
    TextView txt;
    ImageView img;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    MyHolder holder = new MyHolder();
    View view;

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.international_layout,null);
    holder.txt =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtInternational);
    holder.img =(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageInternational);

    holder.txt.setText(names[position]);
    holder.img.setImageResource(varsityimg[position]);

    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Clicked on "+names[position],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    return view;

}
```

}

I want when I click the versity name then go to versity website.But I can't resolve this..please help me..